# How can I use an if/else statement inside modifier parameters in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and the code below is definitely incorrect in some way... It is showing me an error of: "Expected expression in list of expressions"

I have a .navigationBarItems modifier with leading: and trailing: parameters. For the leading parameter, I have previously set it as EditButton(). Now I want to add a condition, that if a condition is true, it will set the button's opacity to 0.0, and if false, it will remain at 1.0.

Any ideas how I should format this?

```
        leading: if (listViewModel.items.isEmpty) {
            EditButton().opacity(0)
        } else { EditButton() }
```

Comment: How about `leading: EditButton().opacity(listViewModel.items.isEmpty ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: @vacawama Thanks so much, it was such an obvious answer. Didn't realise u can use ? and : without State :)